# Percolation in a 2D Ising model

Tags: statistical-mechanics, ising-model, percolation

For a [2D Ising model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ising_model#Two_dimensions) with zero applied field, it seems logical to me that the phases above and below T_c will have different [percolation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percolation_theory) behaviour. I would expect that percolation occurs (and hence there is a spanning cluster) below T_c and that it does not occur (no spanning clusters) above T_c. I'm looking for conformation that this is true, but haven't found anything so far. Is my conjecture correct?

Comment: Yes your conjecture is right. The Ising model is connected to the bond-correlated percolation model. See [this](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v29/i9/p5103_1) paper.

Comment: Thanks, though my suspicions were that it is related to site percolation. Specifically, I would expect that the spin configuration of the high temperature Ising model can be mapped to the configuration of sites for p \approx 1/2 bond percolation. I suppose that the bond-correlated percolation mapping also works at finite temperature.

Comment: @VijayMurthy it would be great if you post that as an answer (and just add a few words about the argument given in the paper).

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75841/226902

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You conjecture is correct. One can relate the 2d Ising model with the bond correlated percolation model. The details are in the paper [Percolation, clusters, and phase transitions in spin models](http://prb.aps.org/abstract/PRB/v29/i9/p5103_1).

The basic idea is to consider interacting (nearest neighbor) spins as forming a bond with a certain probability. One can then show that the partition function of the Ising model is related to the generating function of the bond-correlated percolation model.

The above paper demonstrates that the bond-correlated percolation model has the same critical temperature and critical exponents as the 2d Ising model. However, the values of $T_c$ and the critical exponents seem to be dependent on exactly how one defines a bond. See section III.A.1 in [Universality classes in nonequilibrium lattice systems](http://rmp.aps.org/abstract/RMP/v76/i3/p663_1) (or [arxiv](http://arxiv.org/abs/cond-mat/0205644) version).

Nonetheless your intuitive picture that there would be spanning clusters below $T_c$ and no such clusters above $T_c$ remains valid.

EDIT 21 May 2012

I found [a pedagogical paper](http://dx.doi.org/10.1088/0143-0807/18/3/010) that discusses this issue.