# Is there any book on percolation theory that analyse bond percolation mathematically?

Tags: statistical-mechanics, resource-recommendations, phase-transition, percolation

Introduction to percolation theory, by Stauffer and Aharony, deals with site percolation only. Is there any book which describes mathematically the cluster size distribution, mean cluster size etc for bond percolation?

Comment: [Grimmett's book](https://books.google.ch/books/about/Percolation.html?id=Vnz1CAAAQBAJ&redir_esc=y) is a nice book on bond percolation. However, it is written for probabilists rather than physicists, so it's probably not what you're after (hence this comment rather than an answer).

Comment: Grimmett book is really nice. Here a related question on Grimmett's percolation: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/75841/226902